# Distribution of family's disposable income, given pdf, find $F(y)$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Problem:

In a certain country, the distribution of a family's disposable  income, $Y$, is described by the pdf

$$f(y) = ye^{-y}$$ for $y \geq 0$.
Find the $F(y)$.

Attempt:  In the book there it says the cdf in the continuous case is just an integral $f(y)$, that is $$F(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{y}f(t)dt$$

Then since this looks continuous too.

Then $$F(y) = \int_{0}^{y}te^{-t}dt$$

Then I would use integration by parts and conclude the answer is:  $1- (1+y)^{e^{-y}}$.

Is this correct? Please, if I this is wrong, please can someone help me set up the problem. Thank you.

Comment: I think it is correct.

Comment: I think there is a typo, it should $1-(1+y)\times e^{-y}$

Comment: That is what I tried to put. I guess then it makes sense.

Comment: Use `(1+y)e^{-y}`, not `(1+y)^{e^{-y}}`.